# EditText auto added "-" (android)

Tags: android, android-edittext

Sorry for my english. Before creating this topic i search in google many examples and this examples dont help me. For example how it work in my phone(android 4.0.4): i want write text "test-test", symbol "-" should add automatically. In my phone its like this:

| - its cursor

```
t|, te|, tes|, test|, test|-, testt|-, testte|-, testtes|-, testtest|-
```

I dont know how fix it. I don't know how fix it. It's simple task but i cant solve it

My code:

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            int len=0;
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                String str = editText.getText().toString();

                if(str.length()==4 && len <str.length()) {//len check for backspace
                    editText.append("-");
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {

                String str = editText.getText().toString();
                len = str.length();
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            }

        });
```

if i try set:

```
editText.setSelection(str.length());
```

it do this

```
t|, te|, tes|, test|, test-|, testt-|, testte-|, testtes-|, testtest-|
```

Comment: Looks like you need only move the caret (insertion position) to the end of the text after inserting the hyphen. Can you try that and see if it works, or if I've misunderstood the problem, add extra clarification?

Comment: @GrahamAsher thanks for answer. I try do like this `if(str.length()==4 && len <str.length()) {str += "-"; product_key.setText(str); }` and its work)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems (as I suspected: see my comment) that the fix is to move the insertion caret to the end of the text after inserting the hyphen.